# Use GitHub API to create a repository from a private template

Tags: r, github, github-api

I'm trying to automate my Rmarkdown workflow by creating a package that will contain some helpful functions. I'd like to be able to call a function (say, `new_manuscript()`) that would create a new project from a private template repository that I have.

Using the `gh` package, I can easily create a new repository:

```
gh::gh("POST /user/repos", name = "test", private = "true")
```

However, there is no argument that can be passed in this API call to specify a template repository. I have found [this Github App](https://github.com/createstructure/rest-createstructure/wiki/REST-Actions) called `createstructure` that seems like it may do what I need to do, but the documentation is not entirely clear to me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [`r-lib/gh`](https://github.com/r-lib/gh) does not seem to include the API call "[Create a repository using a template](https://docs.github.com/en/rest/repos/repos#create-a-repository-using-a-template)"

The normal workaround is to use [gh api](https://cli.github.com/manual/gh_api) call (which [`gh()`](https://gh.r-lib.org/reference/gh.html) should be able to do):

```bash
gh api \
  --method POST \
  -H "Accept: application/vnd.github.v3+json" \
  /repos/TEMPLATE_OWNER/TEMPLATE_REPO/generate \
  -f owner='octocat' \
  -f name='Hello-World' \
  -f description='This is your first repository' \
  -F include_all_branches=false \
  -F private=false
```

Comment: Note that you need new line characters ( `\ ` ) after each `-f` / `-F`

Comment: @JoshJohanning Good point, thank you for the feedback. I have edited the answer accordingly.